# Rc.local in raspberry pi 3 model b

Tags: linux, scripting

I am working on raspberry pi 3 model b arm version, running Debian
I need to run a script on boot, I am doing it with /etc./Rc.local
I followed this cookbook: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-enable-rc-local-shell-script-on-systemd-while-booting-linux-system/    and everything worked just fine, there are some echo logs I am sending to a log.txt file and I see that the commands are executing but when I try to run the script I really need it's not working, all the other commands in the Rc.local file is executing but without the most important one for me.

/etc/rc.local file:

```
> ##Reload deamon
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload && echo "Daemon -> SUCCESS" >> /tmp/mounter_test.txt || echo "Daemon -> FAIL" >>
> /tmp/mounter_test.txt
> ##Checking which user is running
> whoami >> /tmp/mounter_test.txt
> ##Check log
> echo "First try" >> /tmp/mounter_test.txt
> enc /opt&
> 
> if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
>         echo "The mounter is running" >> /tmp/mounter_test.txt else
>         echo "The mounter has failed!!" >> /tmp/mounter_test.txt fi
> 
> exit 0
```

Cat /tmp/enc_test.txt

> ```
> SUCCESS
> root
> First try
> The mounter is running
> ```

systemctl staus rc-local.service ----after boot----

> ```
> ● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
>    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
>   Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
>            └─debian.conf
>            /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
>            └─ttyoutput.conf
>    Active: active (exited) since Tue 2022-05-17 09:37:56 BST; 2min 27s ago
>      Docs: man:systemd-rc-local-generator(8)
>   Process: 477 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> May 17 09:37:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
> May 17 09:37:55 raspberrypi sudo[480]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl daemon-reload
> May 17 09:37:55 raspberrypi sudo[480]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
> May 17 09:37:56 raspberrypi sudo[480]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
> May 17 09:37:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
> ```

One more important thing, if I am running /etc/rc.local in the terminal the encryption is working, so only this command and in the rc.local.

Help would be much appreciated! thank you all :)

Comment: is `enc` in root's `$PATH` ?

Comment: Yes the enc can be /local/bin/enc

Comment: try with full path in script then.